# SQLAlchemy, when do I commit?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'd like to improve the performance of SQLAlchemy, in a single API call, I have commits all over the place, do I instead aggregate these session adds, and do a commit at the end of the API call? Or does it matter if I do it all over the place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commits should happen after a logical block of related calls where you want to save all those records (objects) or none.  If one fails you want them all to fail (rollback).  On the flip side grouping unrelated calls together into a single transaction can cause unexpected side-effects, an unexpected error occurs and something you didn't intend gets rolledback when it really should have saved just fine, this isn't what you're doing but I've seen this before for performance.

Anyway, typically, I have a commit at the end of each API call because I think of the API call as all or nothing deal, I doubt the caller would be happy if I half-saved the data when a unique key violation gets hit somewhere in the middle.

I found this page in the SA documentation, dealing with sessions explained how to lay out my sessions, transactions and such.
[lifespan-of-a-contextual-session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html?highlight=web#lifespan-of-a-contextual-session)